# WordPress custom post type preview not working

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, customization, permalinks

The custom post type

```
function prowpsite_create_custom_post_types()
{

$types = array(
    // Where the magic happens
    array(
        'the_type' => 'news',
        'single' => 'car',
        'plural' => 'cars',
        'rewrite' => 'cars',
        'icon' => 'dashicons-admin-site-alt',
    ),

);

foreach ($types as $type) {

    $the_type = $type['the_type'];
    $single = $type['single'];
    $plural = $type['plural'];
    $rewrite = $type['rewrite'];
    $icon = $type['icon'];

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x($plural, 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x($single, 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('add' . $type['single'], $single),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New ' . $single),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit ' . $single),
        'new_item' => __('New ' . $single),
        'view_item' => __('View ' . $single),
        'search_items' => __('Search ' . $plural),
        'not_found' =>  __('No ' . $plural . ' found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No ' . $plural . ' found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_rest'       => true, // To use Gutenberg editor.
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'block-editor' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => $rewrite),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'excerpt', 'revisions'),
        'menu_icon' => $icon,
    );

    register_post_type($the_type, $args);
}
}
add_action('init', 'prowpsite_create_custom_post_types');
```

/* Flush permalinks */

```
function prowpsite_theme_rewrite_flush()
{flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'prowpsite_theme_rewrite_flush');`
```

Why I can't preview the custom post type "car", the preview link return 404!

`https://example.com/cars/22/?preview=true`

**It works when only it published and the link has the slug like this!!**

`https://example.com/cars/22/test?preview=true`

**How can I fix it?**

**Tried to use**

`add_filter('preview_post_link', 'bitflower_change_post_link', 10, 2);`

and also tried

`add_filter('preview_post_car_link', 'bitflower_change_post_link', 10, 2);`

Saving the permalinks not help

But no way!

Can you help?

Comment: Go to the permalink settings page and re-save the settings then test

Comment: @VijayHardaha Thanks but it isn't fix anything! and I'm using  function ephemeris_theme_rewrite_flush()
{
 flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'ephemeris_theme_rewrite_flush');

Comment: Please share the complete code that you have used to register custom post type and if you have added any extra rewrite rules or anything else similar please add that in your question and explain what you did and why you did.

Comment: I have added the full code

Comment: You have `rewrite` twice in your code, can you please remove `'rewrite' => true,` and then re-save the permalink? What is `22` in url? any idea?

Comment: Oh, you missed `with_front`, you need to add this in your `rewrite` and set it to `false`, like this `'rewrite' => array('slug' => $rewrite, 'with_front' => false )`

Comment: I have removed the duplicated and add this code instead 'rewrite' => array('slug' => $rewrite, 'with_front' => false ) but still the preview return 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been working since adding this code.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'prowpsite_change_post_type_link', 1, 3);
function prowpsite_change_post_type_link($link, $post = 0)
{
if ($post->post_type == 'cars' && (strpos($link, "preview") !== false)) {
    return home_url('cars/' . $post->ID . '/' .  $post->post_name);
} else {
    return $link;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have did

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and everything works fine, however, I want to add some information that might help your understanding of the problem.

When your post is published the preview url will be like this:

```
https://dev.test/cars/test/?preview_id=113&preview_nonce=6cf651d710&preview=true
```

When you're post is not published the preview url will be like this, because it's not published it will not give you a permalink,

```
https://dev.test/?post_type=news&p=115&preview=true
```

so if you'll try `https://dev.test/cars/115/?preview=true` for drafted posts, it will give you 404 for sure.

In your examples, I am guessing `22` is your post ID and when you use `https://example.com/cars/22/?preview=true` without publishing the post you get 404, which is right.

and when you publish the post and use `https://example.com/cars/22/test?preview=true` and it will redirect you to `https://example.com/cars/test` that is also right.

So everything is right with your code nothing is wrong.

**CONCLUSION**

If you need to preview an unpublished post you'll have to use `https://example.com?post_type=news&p=22&preview=true`, this url pattern.

Comment: That mean I must edit the URL manually every time, even that I tested the URL like https://dev.test/cars/test/?preview_id=113&preview=true but not working!

Comment: You have a preview button in the backend you don't need to manually type and open url. wordpress will open the preview in a new tab with valid url params.

Comment: The preview button link displays https://dev.test/cars/22&preview=true. Not like as you mentioned

Comment: I am afraid, you have added some sort of customization, and you didn't clearly specify your question. However, if you're clicking on **Preview Changes** on a classic editor or **Preview** in a block editor you'll have preview ID and nonce in url by default. and if you have done some customizations then it's on your customization how they handle it.